# Assertion fail despite correct value?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, assert

I'm running some code to cross-product a matrix with a vector like so:

```
def matrix_multiplication(H, lst):
    # your code here
    print("H:", H)
    x = len(H) # number of rows in H
    y = len(H[0]) # number of cols in H
    vectorSize = len(lst) # length of vector
    assert y == vectorSize, 'number of cols in First Matrix must equal number rows in second term'
    
    # with number of rows of H and number of cols of lst
    result = [[0]*1 for z in range(x)]
    print("Empty result: ", result)
    
    # iterate through rows of H
    for i in range(0, x-1):
        k = 0
        for j in range(0, y-1):
            print("i: ", i)
            print("j: ", j)
            print("k: ", k)
            result[i][0] += H[i][j] * lst[k]
            k += 1
    
    return result
    print("Result: ", result)
```

When I run the test here:

```
A1 = [[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1]]
b1 = [1,1,1,0]
c1 = matrix_multiplication(A1, b1)
print('c1=', c1)
assert c1 == [1,1,0] , 'Test 1 failed'
```

I get AssertionError: Test 1 failed.

By printing the result array before returning, I can see that the value of the array is correct. What is causing this error?

Comment: _I can see that the value of the array is correct_ - well, `[[1], [1], [0]]` is not the same as `[1,1,0]`

Comment: ahhhh i knew it was something stupid. thanks!